# Describing disdain on someone's face

Tags: synonyms, writing-style, story

I have tried to create a description of a face that shows a condescending feeling towards the person they are looking at, also hinting to a past of abuse due to power dynamics. I haven't done much of using face descriptions in writing to show a full picture, so any resource or help you can provide will be appreciated

Context:

> "We're putting this behind us" he finally says.
>
> "But..."
>
> He turns to her, his face [disdain features]... she turns her head to
> the floor avoiding eye contact.

It's for a school project where we are emulating the themes or features shown in the short story flexion from a house on fire.

Comment: You can describe what you actually see, nose, mouth, eyes, mustache, chin, brows, etc, and create the visual picture that the reader will identify with the appropriate emotion, OR you can cheat and rely on telepathy _He read disdain in her eyes_ (he looked it up in the book, and yup, it was Disdain).

Answer (score 1):

> He turned to her with a ***contemptuous*** face...

***Contemptuous*** means

> expressing contempt:
>
> - a contemptuous manner/laugh ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contemptuous))

[WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/contemptuous.html) has plenty of synonyms so you can choose.

It is not the most common of expressions, as it is formal, but it is used in literary works:

> "Oh , it's worse than foolish ; it's downright sneaking , you know," replied Lowten , nibbing the pen ***with a contemptuous face***. ([The Posthumous Papers of the Pickwick, Charles Dickens](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=r2ooAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA565&lpg=PA565&dq=%22with%20a%20contemptuous%20face%22&source=bl&ots=vZjbdN7_oa&sig=ACfU3U0cksUmacGXthdyPwDebSImeT7Aeg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfgvro2N3xAhXPiVwKHaXmBPkQ6AEwEnoECBQQAw#v=onepage&q=%22with%20a%20contemptuous%20face%22&f=false))

[GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with%20a%20contemptuous%20face&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20a%20contemptuous%20face%3B%2Cc0) shows that its use is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

“He turned to her sneeringly ...” or “he turned to her, his face sneering, ...”

> Sneeringly =  in a way that is rude and does not show respect
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sneeringly)

From

> Sneer = an unkind expression on your face that shows you do not respect or approve of someone or something
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sneer)

A relevant quotation comes from Shelley's poem *Ozymandias*:

> I met a traveller from an antique land,
> Who said—“Two vast and trunkless legs of stone
> Stand in the desert. . . . Near them, on the sand,
> Half sunk a shattered visage lies, whose frown,
> And wrinkled lip, and sneer of cold command ...
>
> [Poetry Foundation](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/46565/ozymandias)

Comment: I feel the answer is brief and self-explanatory so wonder why improvements are sought. However, I have added an example of the use of sneer.